# Are there compilers capable of suggesting optimizations that would absolutely require programmer approval?

Tags: compilation, compiler-optimization, compiler-theory, logical-operators, short-circuiting

### Can compilers do more than strict semantically-equivalent optimizations, if we keep the human in the loop?

There are some potential optimizations that are dismissed outright by compilers, because they *may* not be semantically equivalent.

However, they *may* also be fine, so why not attempt to detect and suggest them?  Detection could involve a two-stage process: a compile-time analysis stage and a run-time profiling stage.

### Errors, Warnings, and... Suggestions?

Compilers already do something similar with "warnings", in the sense that they are pooled during each compilation, and sit there forever in a list until you address them to the compilers satisfaction.  Why not have a "Suggestions" or "Suggested Optimizations" section that functions in a similar fashion, and has the potential improve your application's performance?

If a compiler was to analyze Boolean expressions for complexity, estimated runtime, likelihood of individual operands being true vs. false, etc., then it could create a list of suggestions, such as a better order for an expressions operands, and present the suggestions as a list to the programmer.  The programmer could then address them individually, and decide to ignore them, or have the code-editor implement the suggestion.

### Optimizing Boolean Expression Operand Order

Consider the **"Optimization of Short-Circuited Logical Expressions"**.  Because the order of operands affects which operand may be "short-circuited" (i.e. not called), the order of operands in simple Boolean expressions (i.e. A && B && C) is something that (I think) is left untouched by the compiler to avoid introducing unknown side-effects if any operand has side-effects.

Consider this:

```
char c = reader.ReadChar(); //Stream bs; const string NEWLINE;
while (!IsStringPresent( c, bs, NEWLINE ) && c != ',')
```

Since comparing a character is (faster/less complex), it should come first in the expression so short-circuit logic can avoid a call to IsStringPresent when a comma is encountered. It's also true, in this case, that commas (many per line) would be encountered more frequently than new line sequences.

```
char c = reader.ReadChar(); //Stream bs; const string NEWLINE;
if (c != ',' && !IsStringPresent( c, bs, NEWLINE )) //faster for short-circuit; plus ',' is encountered more often than newline
```

### Summary

Objectively, an optimal operand order could be determined for any expression "A && B" based on "Frequency that A is false vs B to trigger a short-circuit" and "Cost of computing A vs B, favoring short-circuiting of the more costly one".  If a compiler could determine approximate values of either of these, at compile-time, run-time, or both, then it could determine that a particular expression may be sub-optimal, and it could create a suggested change for the programmer to implement.

Do any compilers do anything like this today?  If not, why?

Comment: For your short circuit example, the problem the compiler has is that IsStringPresent may have a side effect, that would be incorrect to NOT do. So yes, the compiler would have to ask. It would have to write down a list of assumptions, and you'd have to review it. Once that list got long, it would be a source of bugs: an assumption changes, you don't notice it in the list, it is wrong, and now an optimization goes bad. And if you're going to have to write down an answer as a bunch of keystrokes, why not do so by writing the keystrokes that reorder the operands yourself?

Comment: Regarding short circuiting in general: what the compiler *could* do is decide if the called function has side effects based on the last compilation of it.   Then it can reorder operands based on the last compilation result, and the cost of operations as you have suggested.

Comment: First, it is precisely because of short-circuiting, that including side-effects is to be avoided.  Compilers play it safe by avoiding changes to the order of operands.  If programmers play it safe, as often suggested, by not including hidden "required side-effects" in our short-circuited expressions, then it should be safe to reorder operands in a logically-equivalent manner.  If that's the case, and that's where I'm coming from... then we SHOULD be optimizing that order (indeed HUMAN must decide), and I think the compiler could assist us without it getting very complicated at all.

Comment: If the compiler knows that the called functions in a short-circuit expression are indeed side-effect free, there are no huerstics required. It can evaluate the operands in any order, and so it should choose the cheapest ones first.  The question is, how does the compiler know? a) you assert (possibly being wrong), b) the compiler examines the called function, c) you declare the function to be side effect free (FORTRAN "pure") and the compiler enforces it.

Comment: The compiler wouldn't try to detect side effects, that's the human's job.  It would consider an expression like (A && B && C && D), look at which OPs are the best "short-circuiters" (i.e. most likely to be False), and also look at the cost of evaluating each OP (simple comparison vs expensive function call) at compile-time in terms of complexity, stack size, etc.  If expression looks sub-optimal, then it could profile the actual run-time evaluation costs, and finally suggest an optimum order.  I don't see anything confusing about saying "Hey, (B && D && A && C) may be a faster ordering!"

Comment: But yes, that's what I'm saying.  Right now, we guess at the right order, and are often wrong.  The compiler doesn't ask me anything, so I know it's not even trying to help.  There are profiling tools, but we're on our own with them.  Wouldn't it be great if these tools were integrated, with us in the loop, in such a way that they were more automated and effective?

Comment: We're in violent agreement here modulo how the compiler finds out about side effects (therefore safety of optimization). The reordering business to minimize time is understood by the compiler community pretty well; whether that's actually in your compiler is decided by your friendly compiler vendor. Have you tried GCC to see what it does if you have several "side effect" free conditions, some with complex arithmetic, and some not: For instance what code do you get with.... if (x^10>y && y>1) ...?

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that allowing the optimizer to short circuit a function call just because a programmer thinks it would be ok, is a recipe for untracable bugs. Does it ask during each compile? I dunno; just sounds like there would be a lot of issues with something like this.

Comment: Oh, no.  The assumption is that short-circuiting ALWAYS occurs, such as in C#.  By "decide whether to short-circuit" I mean "a particular operand", by deciding to order it first or second in the expression.  The second expression will be short-circuited, whereas the first is always evaluated.

Comment: It would of course check for potential optimizations during each compilation, and pool them in a list, like it does with compilation "warnings".  If the programmer makes a suggested change, then it obviously wouldn't be detected during the next compilation.  Otherwise, it could just sit there forever like warnings do now.

Comment: Yeah, so I'm saying... "optimization of short-circuit expressions" is to decide the best order of operands, by putting FIRST the operands that are fastest/most-likely-to-trigger-a-short-circuit-of-the-latter-operands, and putting LAST the operands that are slower-running/more-desired-to-be-short-circuited.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is "probably" but "is this what we really want to do?"

Perhaps you're suggesting the compiler detects a possible isomorphism that it isn't sure is an isomorphism and so it asks the programmer "is this an isomorphism", but in any case "if so, if I apply it, will it result in faster code, do you think?"

My thought, however, is more like this: "Hey programmer, if we could do this we'd get much faster code, however, the semantics are different! We would have to strengthen the pre-condition of this function to do this optimisation. Is that OK?"

Strengthening a pre-condition may be OK, heck, the programmer probably didn't even write a pre-condition. If the programmers says "Sure, that's OK" and the programmer is wrong, then with any luck testing would reveal the problem with a "Pre-condition failure".

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is mainly the task of a programmer. To some extent there are tools like static-analysis-tools or refactoring-tools which could be extended to accomplish what you want.

Compilers task is to play within the rules of standard (as much as possible). For some (aggressive) optimizations compilers do provide specific flags which can be passed to enable/disable them
e.g. vectorization, inlining, inter-procedural etc. -- these optimizations are difficult to do by hand.

Reordering (in the example you mentioned) is restricted by C, C++ standard because they might change the semantics of the program. In cases when there is no side effect by the operations, it is possible to reorder them and compilers do such stuff during instruction scheduling (at -O2 in clang++ and g++) but I'm not sure how many other compilers do that.